# Different syntax highlighting in the same file for different languages

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to use more than one syntax highlighting schemes in one file?

Specifically, I'm interested in having part of a LaTeX code highlighted according to my python syntax highlighting rules:

```
This is an example of embedding python inside \LaTeX.

\begin{pycode}
import random
n = random.randint(10)
\end{pycode}

Here's a random integer: $N=\pyc{print(n)}$
```

In the above example, the code will be generally highlighted according to the syntax file latex.vim, but inside the `pycode` environment and the `pyc` command, it will be highlightex according to python.vim.

Comment: This is possible, but requires some experience to implement. It should work in my plugin [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex), which also provides a lot of other useful features for LaTeX editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168) can highlight certain ranges of lines with a different, embedded syntax.

You can either manually define those sections interactively:

```
:1;/^\\begin{pycode}$/,/^\\end{pycode}$/SyntaxInclude python
```

Or automate this in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex/python_include.vim`:

```
call SyntaxRange#IncludeEx('start="^\\begin{pycode}$" end="^\\end{pycode}$"', 'python')
```

Comment: This is really cool! Many, many thanks! Two comments:
1. It seems like the correct call is `:1;/^\\begin{pycode\}$/,/^\\end{pycode\}$/SyntaxInclude python` (i.e. escaping the last `}`).
2. Right now it only applies to the first occurrence of `\begin{pycode} ... \end{pycode}`. Is there a way to apply it to all occurrences?

Comment: Escaping the } should not be necessary. Yes, the first command only processes a single range. To apply to multiple, use `:global`